# Unity 2020.1.0b12.3931 - Objects from scene 2 are visible in scene 1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know if this is some sort of bug or (which is likely) I'm doing something wrong, but I have two scenes.

`menuScene` is a starting point and it suppose to have nothing but canvas with some input fields, sliders, labels and a button.

Clicking the button moves to `gameScene`, which (by default) contains some objects.

This is what I see when I run the project:

[image]

What do I need to do to make only `menuScene` visible on launch?

Comment: do you have `DontDestroyOnLoad` somewhere? Or are you maybe using additive scene loading? Could you show your Hierarchy?

Comment: @derHugo http://puu.sh/FX1xh/cc5fe9f359.png
I don't have `DontDestroyOnLoad` anywhere.

Comment: But you have additive Scene Loading .. that's why I can see both scenes in your Hierarchy ... could you post the code that is executed to switch the scenes?

Comment: @derHugo https://pastebin.com/4NgUHa10
eventStartButton()

Comment: Can you try this with the last stable version `2019.4` .. you are using an beta version ... usually still full of bugs ;) If it works in another version you should report a bug to Unity ... apparently it interprets your call as additive scene loading

Comment: Is this Hierarchy from PlayMode or before? Meaning it is possible that you have already multiple scenes loaded in the editor even before you enter playmode?

Comment: @derHugo both from before and after start. If I remove `gameScene` from hierarchy, clicking on the button causes an error.

Comment: So first of all: [Multiple Scene editing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) is possible and ok but note that when compiling your app it will anyway only start with a single scene (the top-most in the BuildSettings scene list)! So if your code breaks if you have only one scene loaded then something is already wrong ;) What exactly would that error be? Make sure both scenes are added to the BuildSettings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216064/discussion-between-mr-scapegrace-and-derhugo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Unity 2020.1.0b12 is a **BETA** version and not unlikely to have a lot of bugs. If you are not investigating the most newest features but rather want to implement a serious project you should stick to the latest **stable** Unity Version (currently 2019.4 LTS).

---

You have opened both your Scenes in the Editor! In your Hierarchy I can see both scenes `menuScene` and `gameScene`.

In this case `SceneManager.Load` loads your already existing but currently unloaded (disabled) scene (basically only enables it) but keeps the other scene(s) in place.

---

Note that within the Editor [Multi Scene Editing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) is possible and even if you then start the PlayMode both scenes are still there.

However, in a build later only the top-most scene of the list in the [Build Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) is loaded in single mode!

---

The follow up error you got is due to your scenes not added to the [Build Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html). Simply drag & drop your two scenes into the list in the Build Settings.

Then open only the first scene in the Editor (click `Remove` on the other ones) and then enter PlayMode again. Now it should load your scenes in **single** mode